# Unresolveable error occured in org.mule.tools.maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mule, mule-studio

I am getting the following Error in Maven

Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:
 1.5.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre7/../lib/tools.jar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.jaggedpeak</groupId>
<artifactId>amazon-integration</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>mule</packaging>
<name>Mule amazon-integration Application</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8
    </project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <mule.version>3.7.0</mule.version>
    <mule.tools.version>1.1</mule.tools.version>
    <munit.version>1.1.0</munit.version>
    <mule.munit.support.version>3.7.1</mule.munit.support.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                <inclusions>
                    <inclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-support</artifactId>
                    </inclusion>
                    <inclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-spring-support</artifactId>
                    </inclusion>
                </inclusions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     <plugins>
  </build>
```

Note:
The following are my findings ,My build is pointing to JDK,There is no restriction in downloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

point your project to jdk instead of jre.