# Maven Plugin Creating Couldnot find error

Tags: java, maven, mule, mule-studio

I am using the following plugin in my Maven project

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
        <inclusions>
            <inclusion>
                <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-support</artifactId>
            </inclusion>
            <inclusion>
                <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-spring-support</artifactId>
            </inclusion>
        </inclusions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

While using that Plugin,I am getting the following error as

> Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin
>   org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.1 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact
>   com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0 at specified path C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre7/../lib/tools.jar

But i have configured the JDK instead of JRE.I a

Comment: @Suyog Sathe i am pointing to JDK only

Answer (score 0):

check this link:

[Unresolveable error occured in org.mule.tools.maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349556/unresolveable-error-occured-in-org-mule-tools-maven/43358725#43358725)

Error in the last line does indicate it is still pointing to JRE:
C:\program files\java\jre...

It should be c:\program files\java\jdl1.x.xX\jre